# Trouble integrating valgrind to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, valgrind

I have been trying to install `Valgrinds` tool integration

> (Linux Tools:     http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/update)

with eclipse, but am getting the following error during installation :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Valgrind Tools Integration 1.0.0.201209191645 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.feature.group 1.0.0.201209191645)  
  Missing requirement: **Tools Launcher Core 1.1.0.201209191645 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.tools.launch.core 1.1.0.201209191645) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 3.7.0' but it could not be found**  
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Valgrind Core Plug-in 1.0.0.201209191645 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.core 1.0.0.201209191645)  
    To: bundle org.eclipse.linuxtools.tools.launch.core 0.0.0  
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Valgrind Tools Integration 1.0.0.201209191645 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.feature.group 1.0.0.201209191645)  
    To: org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.ui [1.0.0.201209191645]  
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Valgrind UI Plug-in 1.0.0.201209191645 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.ui 1.0.0.201209191645)
    To: package org.eclipse.linuxtools.internal.valgrind.core 0.0.0
```

I tried to install other `CDT` tools but they are also not getting installed, they are showing the error:

> bundle org.eclipse.cdt.launch 7.0.0 could not be found

and on another occasions:

> bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 1.3.100 could not be found.

I tried searching for the individual packages

> (eg http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.core/runtime/3.6.0)

but could not install them. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CDT is too outdated to run recent linuxtools. And most likely your Eclipse is too old to run a recent CDT.

Install a recent version of Eclipse + CDT, either 3.7 or 4.2.1. Both contain recent enough versions of CDT (8.0 or 8.1) to install linuxtools.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt and correct solution. It did work.